# How to acces to a WebService build in Visual Studio from different computer but in the same network?

Tags: c#, iis, asmx

I built a WebService to for different Users to use inside the same network.

Though I can access the service via localhost, network users can not via my ip:

```
<Myip>//WebserviceName.asmx
```

I cannot access to my Web Service, Any help?

My question is, if i want to access to my webservice from different computers how can do it?

I have to public the webservice and put it in ISS Administrator??

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you can access your service locally?  IIS seems to say otherwise

Comment: Hi @MickyD the picture that I posted is when I have create in ISS administrator the WebService.
When I run my WebService in Visual Studio, it lends me to consume the methods of the web-Service. I dont know if is neccesary to post in the ISS administrator

Comment: When you develop in Visual Studio, are you using IIS Express or IIS?  The latter is recommended because if everything works fine for _you_ whilst debugging in IIS then _you are one step closer that others will be able to connect to IIS too_.  IIS Express sadly **does not**.  Check your project settings

Answer (score 0):

Set up firewall settings (svchost.exe -k netsvcs), to allow access others in local network to your PC on concrete port number, then call from another PC in local network your service via [your local ip address]:[service port number], like 192.168.1.54:56235

**UPD1:** you can call http://[your ip]:[service port]/action

Comment: Thanks for your fast anwser. Sorry but i dont know how to executable that svchost.exe -k netsvcs. Is in the cmd console? or where? 
Thanks

Comment: You need to find out your local port where your SOAP application works. Then goto windows filrewall and add new rule : https://www.windowscentral.com/how-open-port-windows-firewall  or disable firewall at all (only for test): https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-disable-the-windows-firewall-2624505

Comment: Thank you for your answer but yout solution is not worked to me. I disabled firewall at all but when i wanted to access to my webservice i cannot access to the web service, Do you know what could be bad? Thanks

Comment: If you disable the firewall, it does not seem to be able to achieve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely I get to consume the Web Service in others computer on the same networking with this checklist selected.
I up the image where I show you the configuration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odmet.png)

Comment: What is your error message? Can you convert it to English?